# Replacing BeanUtils.setProperty with JSP/JSF EL (expression language)

Tags: jsf, el, apache-commons-beanutils

Is there a way I can explicitly invoke the JSP/JSF expression language (EL) as a replacement for something I might do with `BeanUtils.setProperty` for setting nested and indexed properties?

For example, the call `BeanUtils.setProperty(object, "foo.bar", "value")` will result in calling `object.getFoo().setBar("value")` via reflection.

Is there a way I could do that in EL instead?

What I'm trying to do is analogous to `<h:inputText value="#{object.foo.bar}">` but in a back-end method instead of via the UI, where "object.foo.bar" property expression might be dynamic.  I know `BeanUtils` works but feels somewhat archaic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ValueExpression#setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object%29) for this.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
ValueExpression expression = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
    .createValueExpression(elContext, "#{object.foo.bar}", String.class);
expression.setValue(elContext, "value");
```

Comment: in that example, does 'object' have to be a JSF managed bean or CDI object?  is there a way that I can specify a root object explicitly?